# static pointer to an array of class instances

Tags: c++

I have a class `Product`:

```cpp
class Product{
public:
    int weight;
    static *Product listOfProducts;
}

int main(){
    Product ProductList[100];
    *Product listPointer;
    listPointer = ProductList;
    
    Product::listOfProducts = listPointer;
}
```

I want to get a static pointer field to an array of this class' instances, but I have a bad understanding of how to do this.

Comment: The provided code is invalid and does not make a sense.

Comment: I guess you want an array of instances of the class (not an array of the class members)

Answer (score 2):

Your syntax is wrong.  Namely, you have placed `*` in the wrong places, you are missing a semicolon after the `Product` class declaration, and you are missing a definition for the `Product::listOfProducts` variable.

Try this instead:

```cpp
class Product{
public:
    int weight;
    static Product* listOfProducts;
};

Product* Product::listOfProducts;

int main(){
    Product ProductList[100];
    Product* listPointer;
    listPointer = ProductList;
    
    Product::listOfProducts = listPointer;

    // or simply:
    // Product::listOfProducts = ProductList;
}
```

Comment: Thanks my Brother. My freaking program finally works